# How to test if current time is bigger (later) than the time in a variable?

Tags: php

In a variable $time I have this :

```
Fri, 25 Apr 2014 22:20:54
```

This $time I would like to contrast it with the current date/time.

For example, if the $currentTime is equal to $time or less than $time + 5 minutes, then echo yes.

If I create the same format of date/time for the $currentTime (which I do not know how), will the `if` `=` `||` `<` help me ?

How an I do this?

Comment: you can just use `<=`.

Comment: I hope this link might help? https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime()` objects are comparable:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s', 'Fri, 25 Apr 2014 22:20:54'); 
$now  = new DateTime(); 
if ($date > $now) {
    // it's in the future 
}
```

You can modify either DateTime object using [`DateTime::modify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) if you want to add five minutes or any other amount of time.

```
$date   = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s', 'Fri, 25 Apr 2014 22:20:54'); 
$now    = new DateTime(); 
$future = new DateTime('+5 minutes');
if ($date >= $now && $date <= $future) {
    // it's in the future but less then five minutes so
}
```

Comment: I would like the conditional to be true only for a period of time, for example, to be true for a 5 minutes period

Comment: I am accepting your answer in 2 minutes :) please tell me, why I can't echo the date, or future or now?